# Prevent method from running automatically on server in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript, geocoding

Im trying to create a geocoding method in the server folder but its complaining that address is not defined on page load. It appears the method fires on page load before the input has a value (or has been called) and is causing this behavoir. Is there a way to make the method wait to run until called instead of automatically, or another way around this issue? Aldeed:geocoder only seems to run server side.

My coffeescript method, using aldeed:geocoder

```
geocodeAddress: (address) ->
lat = ''
lng = ''
    addressVar = ''
    geocoder = new GeoCoder(
      geocoderProvider: 'google'
      httpAdapter: 'https'
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyDYjLGrETRt4hPZtXcmzQwRbzlFT1zWwr8')
    geocoder.geocode { 'address': address }, (results, status) ->
        if status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK
          lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat()
          lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng()
            return [lat,lng]
```

The Template event

```
Template.dashboard.events({
  'click #customlocationsubmit'(evt) {
    if (document.getElementById("customlocation")) {
      customLocationValue = document.getElementById("customlocation").value;
    }
    if (typeof customLocationValue === 'undefined' || customLocationValue == "") {
        return false;
    } else {
    customUserLocation = Meteor.call('geocodeAddress',customLocationValue);
  }
  }
});
```

The template

```
<template name="dashboard">
    <div class="template-dashboard">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    {{> addPost}}
                    {{> favoritesSidebar}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                <button id="customlocationsubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>

                    {{> posts}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Click event for styx updated again

```
'click #customlocationsubmit'(evt) {
    if (document.getElementById("customlocation")) {
      customLocationValue = document.getElementById("customlocation").value;
    }
    if (typeof customLocationValue === 'undefined' || customLocationValue == "") {
        return false;
    } else {
    Meteor.call('geocodeAddress', customLocationValue, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      // handle error
      return;
    }
    const [ lat, lng ] = result;
    geoResult = result;
    const sortOrder = (Session.get('posts.sortBy') || {}).date || 1;
    return Session.set('posts.sortBy', {date: -sortOrder});
    return distanceFilter(this, geoResult );
  });
  }

  },
```

helper function for styx

```
distanceFilter(location,customUserLocation) {
    function getDistanceFromLatLonInMi(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
      var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
      var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
      var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1);
      var a =
        Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
        ;
      var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
      var d = R * c; // Distance in km
      var e = d * 0.621371;
      return e;
    };

    function deg2rad(deg) {
      return deg * (Math.PI/180);
    };

    getUser = Meteor.users.findOne({
      _id: Meteor.userId()
    });
    if (getUser){
    userUserName = getUser.username;
    userLocation = getUser.profile.location.split(',');
    };
    eventLocation = location.split(',');
    if (typeof customLocationValue === 'undefined' || customLocationValue == "") {
      customUserLocationVar = userLocation;
    }
      else {
        customUserLocationVar = customUserLocation;
        console.log(customUserLocation);
      }
    distance = getDistanceFromLatLonInMi(customUserLocationVar[0],customUserLocationVar[1],eventLocation[0],eventLocation[1]);
    eventDistance = Math.round(distance);
    filterValue = jQuery('#eventdistance').val();
    if (filterValue) {
      if (eventDistance <= filterValue) {
        return true;
        }
    } else if (eventDistance <= 20) {
          return true;
    } else {
          return false;
    }

  },
```

Comment: Where's the method definition (server side) and the code that calls this method from the client?

Comment: Method is in server folder. Method is called from a helper function inside a template in a view

Comment: Please show the method code and your client code - the code above is almost completely irrelevant to your issue.  Also - do not call methods from helpers, call them from *events* instead. Helpers run more often than you might expect.

Comment: I added the rest of the code, and converted it to event only, but it still complains address is not supplied.

Comment: What is the value of `customLocationValue` when you call the method? Also know that `Meteor.call()` is async, you can't assign the result to a variable directly, you have to look at the result in the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your using `aldeed:geocoder` Meteor package (and one another issue):

1. From the [package documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-geocoder#usage):

   > Geocoding an address is simple. Get a new instance of GeoCoder and then call the geocode method on it, passing in the address string.

   That means that, unlike in npm package, `geocode()` function expects first argument to be a string — the address you'd like to geocode ([source code](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-geocoder/blob/master/geocoder.js#L21))
2. From the same documentation:

   > Note that unlike in the node package, the geocode method is **synchronous**. This makes it simple to use in a server method. If you prefer to pass a callback as the last argument, you can.

   That means, that your server method could (and should) utilize that:

   ```coffeescript
   geocodeAddress: (address) ->
     geocoder = new GeoCoder
       httpAdapter: 'https'
       apiKey: 'AIzaSyDYjLGrETRt4hPZtXcmzQwRbzlFT1zWwr8'

     result = geocoder.geocode(address).pop()

     [ result.latitude, result.longitude ]
   ```
3. As it already has been pointed in comments by Michel Floyd, `Meteor.call` on client is **asynchronous**, so you should do it like this:

   ```js
   Meteor.call('geocodeAddress', customLocationValue, (err, result) => {
     if (err) {
       // handle error
       return;
     }
     const [ lat, lng ] = result;
     // handle success
   });
   ```

**Added**: Response from `geocode(address)` (executed from `meteor shell`):

```
> g.geocode('02068, Ukraine, Kiev')
[ { formattedAddress: 'Kiev, Ukraine, 02000',
    latitude: 50.4501,
    longitude: 30.5234,
    extra: 
     { googlePlaceId: 'ChIJBUVa4U7P1EARxX1LbAvqE6A',
       confidence: 0.5,
       premise: null,
       subpremise: null,
       neighborhood: null,
       establishment: null },
    administrativeLevels: { level2long: 'Kyiv City', level2short: 'Kyiv City' },
    zipcode: '02000',
    city: 'Kiev',
    country: 'Ukraine',
    countryCode: 'UA' } ]
```

Comment: This is clearly the correct answer, but I'm getting undefined when I call the const [lat,lng] outside of the method in the event. Ive tried defining the whole method to a variable, and defining a variable within the result of the call, but still get undefined.

Comment: @Silicabello With `coffeescript` you should pay additional attention to indents and returns. As you can see, my example of meteor method doesn't have `return` statement, that's because in the `coffeescript` the last statement is always returned. If you added something _after_ that — it won't be returned.

Comment: @Silicabello Try to add `console.debug(result)` to your callback of `Meteor.call` to see what is returned.

Comment: I replaced my entire method statement with yours, and thats when I receive the undefined issue. console.debug(result) returns nothing, but console.log reveals the correct output from the geocoder, it just doesnt persist beyond the call

Comment: @Silicabello I don't exactly understand, where do you get this `undefined`. On the server or on the client?

Comment: It shows on the client side if i try to console.log a variable defined in or by that call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155779/discussion-between-silicabello-and-styx).